# Using switch statement and regex to match the format of url path?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use switch-statements with regex conditions to set 'direction' variable depending on the 'url'. I have these sample 'url':

```
1) a. /meat/chicken/C/1/edit
   b. /meat/chicken/c/2/edit
   c. /meat/chicken/new

2) a. /meat/beef/B/1/edit
   b. /meat/beef/b/2/edit
   c. /meat/beef/new
```

Type of meat could vary.

My regex conditions/code are true for these urls:

```js
    if(/[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.\d+.[edit]+/.test(url)){
        switch (true) {
            case /chicken/.test(url):
                direction = 'chicken/edit'
                break;
            case /beef/.test(url):
                direction = 'beef/edit';
                break;
            default:
                direction = 'edit';
                break;
        }
    } else if(/[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.[new]+/.test(url)){
        switch (true) {
            case /chicken/.test(url):
                direction = 'chicken/new'
                break;
            case /beef/.test(url):
                direction = 'beef/new';
                break;
            default:
                direction = 'new';
                break;
        }
    }
```

However, it is true for other urls as well which I do not want, such as:

```
/meat/beef/
```

If 'url' is '/meat/beef/', this is currently returning true on the else if-statement, "(else if(/[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.[new]+/.test(url)){", which I do not want it to be true because it doesn't have the word 'new'.

I just want my if-statements and switch-statements to match and be true for formats of 1) and 2) above.

I am not very fluent in regular expressions and still learning switch-statements. Can anyone help me?

Comment: please add to the pathes the wanted targets.

Comment: The question doesn't seem clear. Maybe tell us what inputs should have what outputs

Comment: @NinaScholz I apologize Nina, I am not understanding what you mean. I just want other paths not listed in 1) and 2) to return false for my current if and else-statement.

Comment: @ktilcu I apologize. I added more descriptions. I just don't want paths other than examples 1)  and 2) to return true. I am having problem where if url is /meat/beef/, it is returning true on the else if-statement when I want it be to false because it doesn't have the word 'new'.

Comment: ahhh ok I see. `[new]` means any of the letters `n`, `e`, or `w` not the combination of them. regex101.com is really useful for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @ktilcu Oh. I see. I did not know that. I actually thought it meant the word 'new'.

Comment: @ktilcu Thank you. I learned that instead of [new], I should be using .new$ to match the exact word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be simpler.

```
const urlParts = url.split('/');
const [base, type] = urlParts;
const action = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1]; // get the last

if (base === 'meat' && (action === 'edit' || action === 'new')) {
  direction = [type, action].join('/');
}
```

Routing libs are hard to get right. I'd use some of the ones that already exist or at least read them for ideas. something like [find-my-way](https://github.com/delvedor/find-my-way#readme) would be a great read.

Comment: This was simpler and more readable answer. Thank you so much!